# Export conda environment without being in a specific environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to export the 'default' environment (as I don't have any environments actually installed and I do most things on the default environment) in Anaconda. I'm on Windows.

```
import sys
sys.version
'3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]'
```

Here's my try and output ..

```
H:\>conda env export
CondaEnvException: Conda Env Exception: Unable to determine environment
Please re-run this command with one of the following options:
* Provide an environment name via --name or -n
* Re-run this command inside an activated conda environment.
H:\>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The default environment name is `root`. Thus,

```
conda env export --name root
```

should do what you want.